# path.join(__dirname, "foo", "bar") vs path.join(__dirname, "foo/bar")

Tags: node.js, path

And by the way, `foo` and `bar` would be string literals

I've seen a bunch of repositories that use both, `"foo/bar"` and `"foo", "bar"`

I did a benchmark with [benchmark js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/benchmark) with the following code (I also made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ocboogie/1610e0363601ae240d8aa2449e3074e8))

```
suite.add('foo/bar', function() {
    path.join(__dirname, 'foo/bar')
})
.add('foo, bar', function() {
    path.join(__dirname, 'foo', 'bar')
})
.on('complete', function() {
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
})
.run({ 'async': true });
```

And `foo/bar` was faster. But I still see a lot of code like `path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'node_modules')`

So is there any reason to use `path.join(__dirname, 'foo', 'bar')`?

I'm also talking about `path.resolve`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three main benefits to using `path.join()`.

1. It automatically checks for trailing separators so you will never get two separators together in the resulting path.
2. It automatically uses the platform-specific path separator (which is a backslash on Windows).
3. After joining the segments with the above logic, it then normalizes the path, resolving any `.` or `..` segments.

So, you use `path.join()` for sure when you want any of this functionality.  If you don't need any of these features, then you can go either way (with your own manual path construction or use `path.join()`).

Comment: So it's completely okay to use something like `path.join(__dirname, "../path/to/dir")`?

Comment: @ocboogie - Yes, it is.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Kind of difficult for anyone to know how to improve the answer if you just do a drive-by downvote with no explanation.